# Industrial switches failing to pass broadcast traffic/ARP requests very slow

Tags: ping, ethernet, arp

I'm dealing with some industrial Ethernet switches (Phoenix Contact FL Switch SF 16TX) which are connected to about 5 computers and 5 SLC/5 PLCs.

We are having an issue where ARP requests are not working and the ARP table shows "invalid" under the Type column for many of the systems, preventing some of the PCs from reaching the desired destinations.

I connected everything to one switch, eliminating the other one, and then I started getting valid MAC/IP addresses in the ARP table and was able to ping other hosts.  However, the first few pings timeout with destination not found.  It takes several seconds for the computer to get its ARP table updated, then pings are fine (occasionally a dropped one).

This setup has been in operation for around 10 years - could these switches be failing?  Could they just be too slow for the broadcast traffic and the other stuff that's going across them?

UPDATE: The issue of some computers losing connection occurred again.  I only have one switch connected.  The Windows 10 computer was unable to ping or be pinged by any other computer.  The old SCADA computers (XP) maintained connection with each other and with the PLCs. At this point, only one switch is being used - the other is disconnected from the network.

NOTE: We are using fiber-to-ethernet adapters to connect various buildings - could these be injecting bad or repetitive traffic?

Answer (score 1):

> I connected everything to one switch, eliminating the other one, and
>   then I started getting valid MAC/IP addresses in the ARP table and was
>   able to ping other hosts. However, the first few pings timeout with
>   destination not found. It takes several seconds for the computer to
>   get its ARP table updated, then pings are fine (occasionally a dropped
>   one).

That sounds pretty normal. In order for ping to work, both the switch and the host need to build their ARP table for the pinged ip address. I'd expect the first few ping responses to fail until the relevant ARP tables are updated. Once the relevant ARP tables are updated then every ping should work, until the ARP table is flushed. Then rinse and repeat.

Since one switch seems to work fine, test the other switch the same way. If it works fine then reconnect both switches and see if the problem reoccurs.

Do these switches support Spanning Tree Protocol? Is it possible that you have a switch loop when both are connected?

Comment: They are unmanaged switches.